# iOS: Blocks, main queue, and retain cycles

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have the following call within my app:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.emptyView.hidden = [self.recordsData count];
        [self finishedRefreshing];
    });
```

which led me to believe that since we are accessing an ivar, a retain cycle would be created.  But since I don't see the block being captured within self I figured I'd be ok.  This then led me to believe we've been over using the weakself pattern as our typical convention is never to actually assign a block as an ivar.  I still feel I'm missing something, are there other ways to create a retain cycle without assigning the block to self?  I'm not sure why I'm having such a hard time grasping this concept but any good reading sources are also appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "cycle" part does seem to be overlooked when people worry about retain cycles. In your code, the block is managed by GCD, your objects don't own it, so there is no retain cycle.

> we've been over using the weakself pattern

It does seem the case that a lot of people think "aargh! Blocks! Make a `weakSelf`"!

The retain cycles happen when an object owned by the block (so, a strong reference to the object or one of its ivars) itself owns the block (so the block is copied to a property or ivar).

The typical case is when you've made an object such as a custom alert view that has a completion handler block, and within the block you do something with the object itself (e.g. remove the view from its superview).

Comment: Thanks, after a little bit more research I think it somewhat clicked.  Think what I was missing was that when you call a function with a block parameter on an object, Block_copy will be called and that's why this sample creates a cycle : [obj dosomething:^{ [obj doMore]; }];  I understood the second part of the reference but not how the first part was created.  Thanks for your help, makes sense.

Comment: Hi jrturton, I saw an other example where somebody said the following snippet could cause a retain cycle:  dispatch_async(queue, ^{
   [self doSomething];
});  my assertion is that this is false, no retain cycle is created. Block_copy is called but nobody is retaining the block.  Is this assumption correct?

Comment: It's not correct to say that "nobody" is retaining the block (the GCD mechanism will be) but certainly `self` isn't retaining it and that's all that matters in this case.